# Anomalous behaviour with TreeSet() with custom comparator

Tags: java, list, collections, set, treeset

What I've done in the below program is, I've created a TreeSet named "alls" with a custom comparator which compares two list and if they are equal it returns 0 else returns 1. But if I add two same list into TreeSet then TreeSet accepts two same list into it. But it should not contain two same list cuz i've defined a comparator like that.

```
   List<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(1);add(2);add(3);add(4);}};
    List<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(1);add(1);}};
    List<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(2);add(1);}};
    List<Integer> a4 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(3);add(1);}};
    List<Integer> a5 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(4);add(1);}};
    List<Integer> a6 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(5);add(1);}};
    
    Comparator b1 = (l1,l2)->{if(l1.equals(l2)) return 0; else return 1;};
    Collection<List<Integer>> alls = new TreeSet(b1);
    alls.add(a1);
    alls.add(a1);
    alls.add(a1);
    alls.add(a2);
    alls.add(a3);
    alls.add(a1);
    alls.add(a4);
    alls.add(a6);
    alls.add(a5);
    alls.add(a2);
    alls.add(a1);
```

When I try to Print my TreeSet(name alls) then the following output shows up:

1 2 3 4

1 1

2 1

1 2 3 4

3 1

5 1

4 1

You can see [1 2 3 4] is inserted into my TreeSet(whose name is alls) twice but it does not get inserted after.

How is this possible? I though TreeSet with my custom comparator doesn't allow duplicates. Also if it allows why not the same elements doesn't get inserted further in my program

Comment: Because your `Comparator` is wrongly implemented. (it never returns `-1`

Comment: sry But what is the use of -1?

Comment: 0 means it doesn't insert 1 means it inserts

Comment: That's entirely not how the `Comparator` interface works: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html): *Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second*

Comment: can tell me how to change this comparator with -1 like you said?

Comment: @Lino is right but it only means his `TreeSet` will be unsorted. This Comparator should prevent duplicates (at least looks like preventing duplicates) ...

Comment: but why it doesnt work? @IQbrod

Comment: why it allow duplicates

Comment: thanks for the solution @Lino but can you tell me why my implementation is allowing duplicates at first and then blocking further ? it'll be helpful for me to understand

Comment: Because a Tree is sorted from the middle value and you always append as bigger number (1) and never as lower (-1).
Comparing `a1` with other value will result in a difference as rest of the tree is not well sorted

Comment: @ALLAN I think it is because the your comparator implementation is flawed, the treeset is based on a Tree with different brancher, so with your comparator it either stays always on the same branch or goes always left, but never right. depending on the underlying java implementation it could be that these initial `a1` were somehow placed on different branches, and thus you have duplicates

Comment: @ALLAN Additionally if you only want distinct values, why not use a `HashSet` in the first place? There seems to be no real need of yours to use a `TreeSet`

Comment: From the `Comparator#compare` JavaDocs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-): `The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.` You are breaking (at least) this contract, thus the behaviour is not well defined.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java

Comment: @IQbrod Thanks for your answerrr..:) Do you have a solution for my problem? I've looking for so long..

Comment: @Lino THanks the hashSet solution worked Thanks. But how to solve this problem with TreeSet or is TreeSet somewhat flawed?

Comment: @ALLAN I think treeset is not right suit for you because you don't really care about order

Comment: Side note:  [Don’t use double brace initialization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)  It has no benefit and carries a hidden price.

Answer (score 3):

Your Comparator doesn't work

```java
Collection<List<Integer>> alls = new TreeSet(b1);
alls.add(a1);
alls.add(a2);
alls.add(a3);
```

Your implementaton sorts two different list with the second always bigger due to `return 1` so your Tree looks like :

> a1 <- a3 -> a2

Now let's add a1 :

```java
Collection<List<Integer>> alls = new TreeSet(b1);
alls.add(a1);
alls.add(a2);
alls.add(a3);
alls.add(a1);
```

> a1 <- a3 ? a1 -> a2 RESULT a1 is bigger
> a1 <- a3 -> a2 ? a1 RESULT a1 is bigger
> a1 <- a3 -> a2 -> a1

Your tree has now duplicated a1.
**SOLUTION** : Use a correct `Comparator` mentionned in comments

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        Comparator<List<Integer>> b1 = (l1, l2)->{

        if(l1.equals(l2)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if(l1.isEmpty())
                return 1;
            if(l2.isEmpty())
                return -1;

            int i = 0;
            while (l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(i))) i++;

            if(l1.get(i) > l2.get(i))
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }};
```

Your comparator doesn't handle the situation when one list "is lower" than the second. Your comparator returns only 0 and 1. I think that TreeSet uses binary search or any faster method to find an object and check if is a particular object is a set. Methods like that need to have clearly defined whether an object is greater or lower than others. If TreeSets use primitive comparing by equal object with each in the set your comparator would be working. In sorted structures are more complex and better methods to find an object.

Comment: Will fail when `a` or `b` or both are empty

Comment: I know, that was just an example. My suggestion is to find first not equal elements in the list and compare them.

Comment: Here is a proper soluton:
        Comparator<List<Integer>> b1 = (l1, l2)->{if(l1.equals(l2)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if(l1.isEmpty())
                return 1;
            if(l2.isEmpty())
                return -1;

            int i = 0;
            while (l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(i))) i++;

            if(l1.get(i) > l2.get(i))
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }};